# How to receive data using Bluetooth Server Socket RFCOMM in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, rfcomm

I am trying to make an android application that receives and display the data coming from a paired Bluetooth device. I have a working python code and I want to write the similar code in android.I can run Python in Android phone but no UI! The code find the port using RFCOMM and then connects using socket .The address of the Bluetooth device is in XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX format and I am not sure how to write the code for android.Would appreciate it if you help me! Thanks!
Here is my python code:

```
from bluetooth import *
from sys import stdout

server_address = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
#port = get_available_port( RFCOMM )
try:
  my=sock
except:
  sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
  sock.connect((server_address, 1))
  print "connected"
else:
  print "---"
  data=0
while 1:
data= sock.recv(1)
if data== '':
  print "Socket broken"
else:
  data= data
  print "received"
  print text 

sock.close()
sock=None
del sock
```

Can this android code help?

```
String deviceAddress = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX";
adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

BluetoothDevice device = _adapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);

try {
    socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BluetoothSerialUuid);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    socket.connect();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: did u see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680259/using-sockets-to-send-and-receive-data.??

Comment: yes,but how you set up receive socket?

Comment: try http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/simple-communication-using.html

Comment: This uses internet :( i want to use bluetooth!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158828/bluetooth-socket-connection :)

Comment: why cant you  search effectively..:(

Comment: I did but didn't find what I am looking for:(

Answer (score 1):

You can find the full source code for this sample in your SDK at:

`<sdk>/platforms/android-<version>/samples/`

which has name `BLUETOOTH CHAT` see that code and filter what you want :)

Comment: This is a good example for sending data but how can can I change it so it would only connect to deviceAddress = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" and receive data:) Thanks

Comment: first you want to pair a bluetooth device,after you can send recive in android,programmatically.read it here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html

Comment: another question: how can I make the UI update the received data instead of printing every data in one line?!